# MySQL - best way to store YYYY-MM-DD date column for later retrieval as unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I have a readings table with daily samples. Therefore I have a column called 'date'. I need to select the date as a unix timestamp.

Currently I have this:

- date column uses **[date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)** type
- insert format is YYYY-MM-DD
- on insert, only care about date not time (so probably stored as UTC **YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00**?)
- server timezone is UTC+2

I need the unix timestamp of **UTC YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00** (start of the day). But it seems MySQL stores the dates as UTC values, then converts them back to the server timezone when retrieved. So:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date_stamp` ...
```

... actually returns a unix timestamp for the previous day (**YYYY-MM-DD 22:00:00**).

So then I've considered using CONVERT_TZ, but I have a Windows server so it seems any query returns NULL unless I configure **[time zone description tables](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)**:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`date`, 'UTC', 'SYSTEM'))) AS `date_stamp` ...
```

Am I doing it right? Am I using the best date format? Am I converting the best way?

Comment: Unix timestamps are always in UTC. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_FIELD)` should always give you the same number regardless of server timezone settings. How are you converting it to a readable date?

Comment: @Vatev  - database insert uses PHP DateTime: **$date->format('Y-m-d')**. Database select is the second statement above: **SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`date`, 'UTC', 'SYSTEM'))) AS `date_stamp` ...**. Rendering is via the Flot JavaScript chart library (which takes a JavaScript timestame, i.e. unix timestamp * 1000). This works but seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

try select your date field like this

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(date)) date from myTable;
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: this still returns the timestamp for the date in the server's timezone, not for the date in UTC.

Comment: Then try with this functions: UTC_DATE(), UTC_TIME() or UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Comment: As these return the [current UTC date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-date), I don't really see how that helps either.